# Subversion auto-props woes

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn, ankhsvn

This is driving me nuts so any advice from fellow users would be welcome.  I am using Subversion, with a copy of VisualSVN 1.6.1 installed on a Windows server.  On my PC I am using a combination of TortoiseSVN and the wonderful AnkhSVN Visual Studio plugin.  Everything works like a dream, but now I am trying use the `svn:keywords` feature so I can include `$Id$` at the top of all my source files.  Now, for existing files I can edit the SVN properties and add this keyword and it all works fine, but I want this done automatically for new files - and I cannot make it work.

According to the documentation you need to edit a special Subversion Config file located in your `C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Application Data\Subversion` folder.  My PC already had a copy of this file, so I changed it to look like this:

```
[miscellany]
enable-auto-props = yes

[auto-props]
*.cpp = svn:eol-style=native;svn:keywords=Author Date Id HeadURL Revision
*.hpp = svn:eol-style=native;svn:keywords=Author Date Id HeadURL Revision
*.rc = svn:eol-style=native;svn:keywords=Author Date Id HeadURL Revision
*.rc2 = svn:eol-style=native;svn:keywords=Author Date Id HeadURL Revision
*.cc = svn:eol-style=native;svn:keywords=Author Date Id HeadURL Revision
*.c = svn:eol-style=native;svn:keywords=Author Date Id HeadURL Revision
*.h = svn:eol-style=native;svn:keywords=Author Date Id HeadURL Revision
*.wsf = svn:eol-style=native;svn:keywords=Author Date Id HeadURL Revision
*.js = svn:eol-style=native;svn:keywords=Author Date Id HeadURL Revision
*.htm = svn:eol-style=native;svn:keywords=Author Date Id HeadURL Revision
*.html = svn:eol-style=native;svn:keywords=Author Date Id HeadURL Revision
*.css = svn:eol-style=native;svn:keywords=Author Date Id HeadURL Revision
```

I then added a new file to an existing Visual Studio project (from within Visual Studio), added `$Id$` to the top and committed it - but, alas, the `svn:keywords` property is not being set.

Does anyone know how to get this working?  I even tried adding settings to the registry (in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Tigris.org\Subversion\Config`) but still no joy.  I then tried messing with Config files on the SVN server itself, but nothing seems to work.

I have obviously missed something blindingly obvious!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, the issue lies with AnkhSVN. The keywords properties will not be automatically added if the new file is added in Visual Studio (with AnkhSVN 2.0.5250). It will only be added if you add the file using Tortoisvn.

I downloaded a trial version of VisualSVN (plugins to Visual Studio). It does not have this issue. Properties are automatically added to new files added in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the answer is just some silly quotes around the actual keywords :)

```
[auto-props]
*.cpp = svn:eol-style=native;svn:keywords="Author Date Id HeadURL Revision"
```

Comment: My problem was making this change on the server when it (unfortunately) need to be made on the client!

Comment: Note also, that autoprops in the config file only take effect if you add or import.   If your file is already under svn control, you will need to manually give it the keyword properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be sure you've picked the correct config file, use TortoiseSVN's edit button: [Subversion Wiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Subversion/auto-props).

The only similar problem I could find was a user complaining about this not working with uppercase file extensions, but this is for Fedora, not for Windows: [link](http://osdir.com/ml/version-control.subversion.tortoisesvn.user/2006-10/msg00413.html)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with AnkhSVN.  I did some tests outside of Visual Studio, using TortoiseSVN to add the files, and it started working (using my user config file).  I will try the latest AnkhSVN to see if this makes any difference.

I'd prefer to have this done at the server end, but this seems to be user-specific.

Either way, thanks for the pointers Len and schnaader.

Comment: AnkhSVN caches your Subversion user settings. You should restart Visual Studio to reapply the global settings.